# how to get data from another datatable

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

how do i get data from sql table into my other listview i had got it to work with the data but can't get it to work with hast

```
    public SqlConnection conn;
    public SqlCommand cmd;
    string connstring = (@"Data Source=SINDALSQL\MSSQL14; Initial Catalog=OminiData; Integrated Security =True");
    string data = ("SELECT Billed, Mærke, Model, Årgang, [Motor Type], Krydsmål, Centerhul, Møtrik, Bolter, Dæk, Fælge FROM Hjuldata");
    string hast = ("SELECT Kode, Hastighed FROM Hastighed_indeks");

    private void win_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        binddata();
        bindhast();
    }
```

this one works

```
    private void binddata()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(data, connstring))
        {
            adp.Fill(dt);
            hjuldata.DataContext = dt;
        }
    }

<GridViewColumn Header="Mærke" Width="140" >
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Path=Mærke}" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" />
</DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

and this one is the one i got trouble with

```
    private void bindhast()
    {
        DataTable dts = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter adph = new SqlDataAdapter(hast, connstring))
        {
            adph.Fill(dts);
            hast_list.DataContext = dts;
        }
    }

 <GridViewColumn Header="Hast Symbol"
 DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Kode}"
 Width="300"/>
 <GridViewColumn Header="Max Km/t"
  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Hastighed}"
                                Width="200"/>
```

thats the whole code for the listview

```
<ListView x:Name="hast_list" Background="#FF303030" BorderBrush="#FF303030" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="431" Canvas.Left="632" Canvas.Top="34" Width="607">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:TypeGridViewColumnHeader}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFEAEAEA" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                </Style>
                            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Hast Symbol"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Kode}"
                                Width="300"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Max Km/t"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Hastighed}"
                                Width="200"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: If you want one dataset that reads from multiple tables ... then it soiunds like you want a [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Comment: Why do you put `(` and `)` around your string constants?

Comment: on win_loaded, if you run bindhast() before binddata(), does it have the same behavior?

Comment: and it doesn't matter in wich priotie i set them

Comment: i am not sure if thats a join statement i need for that since is 2 tables that have diffrent types of data that i wan't to fill the whole tables in separately listviews

Comment: You need to call a gridview.DataBind() event to get the tables to show up.

Comment: @Hogan I was thinking the same thing.  It's so odd.  I have never seen anything like it before.

Comment: @JSON -- It is one of two things you see with novice programmers.  1) Extra `(` and `)`    2) Trailing `.ToString()` on every data assignment (including string to string).

Comment: @Hogan Yeah that makes sense.  I knew a guy who used to do things like this.  string myString = "hello".trim();  WTF are you trimming?  It's hard coded!!!

Comment: @JSON be happy he didn't have `string myInt = ("hello".Trim().ToString());`

Comment: @Hogan That's just crazy

Comment: @JSON - sure, but here is a hint from from an old-timer.  It is easier to just delete those questions that get downvoted (for whatever reason) than to stress about it -- if your goal it to get rep.  Better to delete and move on to the next question to answer.

Comment: In order to analyze, we need to identify the meaning of ' trouble' . What is the Exception message? By running the code, which line is problem? All the code inside bindhast() method are passed, completed successfully but the data is not showing in ListView only? Can you check dts is made correctly like through MessageBox.Show(dts.[0][0].ToString()); And seems your code is not entire picture and we're lacking of informations . Where is connection.Open(), Close() ? It seems easysome matter. But we need practical information for insights.

Comment: @Hogan the reason i was using () around my string constanst was becuase i did a copy paste from my connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you are missing

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

this should solve it

```
  <ListView x:Name="hast_list" Background="#FF303030" BorderBrush="#FF303030" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="431" Canvas.Left="632" Canvas.Top="34" Width="607" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:TypeGridViewColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFEAEAEA" />
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            </Style>
                        </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Hast Symbol"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Kode}"
                            Width="300"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Max Km/t"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Hastighed}"
                            Width="200"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the databind event after setting the datasource on both tables.

```
private void binddata()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(data, connstring))
    {
        adp.Fill(dt);
        hjuldata.DataContext = dt;
        hjuldata.DataBind();
    }
}

private void bindhast()
{
    DataTable dts = new DataTable();
    using (SqlDataAdapter adph = new SqlDataAdapter(hast, connstring))
    {
        adph.Fill(dts);
        hast_list.DataContext = dts;
        hast_list.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: is giving me a error
'ListView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: "Accepting first argument of Type ListView"?  There are no arguments. If you are trying to pass the ListView as a parameter, don't do that.  Do it just the way I have written.

Comment: i tryed again with a copy paste and still got the same error

Comment: How are you creating your ListViews?

Comment: that depends on the style one of them have a grouping with expanders where i be using textblocks and then i have one that are just default witch i had postet the code for

Comment: databind is not a listview syntax is a repater syntax for asp.net